# my program isn't using certain part of my code

Tags: c++

I need help with my program, when the user enters a number that is not a lottery winner it still says winner any suggestion how to fix this also if you could give me better suggestions on my linear search function that would be amazing , here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool input(double);

const int LUCKY_NUMS =10;

// Function prototype that searches winning ticket number
bool ticketSearch(const int [], int, int);

int main ()
{
    //user continues playing lotto

    char again;

    const char QUIT = 'N';
    //determines if player's ticket is a winner

    int winningNum;
    //5 digit ticket number entered by player

    int playerNum;
    //holds winning ticket number

    int ticket;

    //Array holding the winning tickets for each week

    int lottoTix[LUCKY_NUMS] = {13579, 26791, 26792, 33445, 55555,
                                62483, 77777, 79422, 85647, 93121};

    //Player decides if they want to continue playing

            for (int week = 0; week < 10; week++)
            {
            //Winning lotto ticket for each week (10 weeks total)

                ticket = lottoTix[week];
                do
               {
                    cout << "Please enter your 5-digit ticket number for     week " << (week + 1) << ": " << endl;

            //Player's ticket number

            cin >> playerNum;
            }while(input(playerNum));



            //Calls linear search for winning lotto ticket

            winningNum = ticketSearch(lottoTix, LUCKY_NUMS, playerNum);

            //Error message if player's number is not the winning ticket
            //here is where my problems occurs it doesn't use this part of code at all
            if (playerNum != lottoTix[LUCKY_NUMS])
            {

                cout << "Sorry, you did not win the MEGAMILLIONS lottery. ";
                cout << "Thanks for playing! ";
                cout << "Play again? (Y/N)";
                    cin >> again;
            }

            //Player wins the lottery
            else if (playerNum == lottoTix[LUCKY_NUMS])
            {

                cout << "You have just won 598 MILLION DOLLARS!!! ";
                cout << "CONGRATULATIONS!!!";
                cout << "Play again? (Y/N)";
                cin >> again;
            }


            if ((again != 'Y') && (again != 'y'))
                {
                    //exit message
                    cout << "Press [Enter] to exit...\n\n";
                    //exits program
                    exit(0);
                }
        }
   return 0;
}

//linear search for winning ticket of the week
bool ticketSearch(const int ticketList[], int numTickets, int winningNum)
{
int index = 0;
int position = -1;
bool found = false;

while ((index < numTickets) && !found)
{
    if (ticketList[index] == winningNum)
    {
        found = true;
        position = index;
    }
    index ++;
    }
    return found;
}
// function does invalid input
bool input(double number)
{
if (number < 0 || number >=99999 ||  cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    cout <<"\nYou have entered an invalid answer\n" << endl;
    return true;
}
 else
     return false;
```

}

I know there are probably some punctuation errors but that is probably the easiest thingt to fix

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Why did you compare playerNum  with lottoTix[LUCKY_NUMS] ? (LUCKY_NUMS is a const integer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the value you get back from the function should be a boolean. winningNum is an integer. In addition, you could use something such as "if an element is found", then do something. You could also use a for loop to do your linear search.